# Meteor accounts-password merge with accounts-google 2017 way

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

So this seems to be a pretty common issue in Meteor. I have configured an auth with accounts-password and with accounts-google. Each creates separate users but I need to link them. Searching for this in stackoverflow and google in general results in outdated packages which do not support accounts-passwords anyway.
So I wonder what's the 2017 way of merging google accounts with password accounts?

Comment: Hi @hayk did you get a chance to resolve the above issue ? Now I am facing the similar issue.

Comment: @SyamKumar sadly we ended up using custom logic for this. It was pretty hacky but there was no other way. Unfortunately it's been years so I don't remember much details now. But I wonder if after all these years it's not solved yet, what a pity.